# update json property value using for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does python have util loop like in javascript? (eg. map, reduce and filter). Or everything must be done manually using for loop?

I have a simple 2 object records like below

```
json = [{
    "id": 1, "name": "a"
}, {
    "id": 2, "name": "b"
}]
```

How can I update name property if id is 2?

```
for index, x in json:
    if(x[id] == 2)
        //what to do here? change name to 'something'
```

Comment: [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)…

Comment: @deceze ah thanks, look like for loop is more readable than python's map

Comment: Python has no concise syntax for complex inline functions. Passing long-ish inline callbacks is a common idiom in Javascript, not so much in Python. In Javascript the standard `for` loop… isn't all that simple, that's why callbacks are more common. Python's `for` is perfectly simple and straight forward though.

Comment: js's for loop does the job but might need 2 variables else mutate the original variable which is a bad practice that's why map come to rescue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straight forward way:

```
for obj in json:
    if obj['id'] == 2:
        obj['name'] = 'something'
```

Objects are mutable, so you're directly mutating the object here. This is the simplest way. The typical Javascript equivalent would be:

```
json.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.id == 2) {
        obj.name = 'something';
    }
});
```

---

The slightly more condensed version:

```
for obj in (o for o in json if o['id'] == 2):
    obj['name'] = 'something'
```

This inlines a generator expression which pre-filters the objects to loop over. Alternatively:

```
for obj in filter(lambda o: o['id'] == 2, json):
    obj['name'] = 'something'
```

Somewhat equivalent to:

```
json.filter(o => o.id == 2).forEach(obj => obj.name = 'something')
```

---

The even more condensed version:

```
json = [{**obj, 'name': 'something' if obj['id'] == 2 else obj['name']} for obj in json]
```

This is a list comprehension which builds a new object and new list, somewhat equivalent to:

```
json = json.map(o => ({...obj, name: obj.id == 2 ? 'something' : obj.name}))
```

You decide what you find most readable…

Comment: thanks for the js reference! any resources for a js dev to best learn python? that will cut short my time to pick this new langguage.

Comment: ‍♂️ I don't know… Learn Python on its own merits, just make sure you *read* a lot of pythonic code to get how things are done. Don't try to port Javascript idioms over.

Comment: ah I see. I thought knowledge js will help.

Comment: Sure, general programming knowledge helps, but you'll find that details like this differ by languages.

Answer (score 2):

Since your json is a list of dicts, you can loop through the dicts while checking your required condition:

```
json = [{
    "id": 1, "name": "a"
}, {
    "id": 2, "name": "b"
}]

for obj in json:
  if obj["id"] == 2:
    obj["name"] = 'something'
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'something'}]
```

Comment: You may want to add `break` after the assignment.

Comment: There might be other dicts with 'id':2 so it depends on the use-case

Comment: why use break? meaning if there's another 2, python will change all the value to 'something'?

Answer (score 1):

(That's a list of dictionaries, not a JSON string.)

The most concise (you can argue about readability) way I can think of is:

```
>>> [{**d, 'name': 'something' if d['id'] == 2 else d['name']} for d in json]
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'something'}]
```

This builds a new list of dicts (not an inplace operation), so you would have to reassign the name `json`.

**edit**: fixed error from misreading the question.

Comment: js's map is readable but I think python doesn't 'care' about mutability so basic loop does the job. am I correct?

Comment: @AndreThonas you asked for something other than a `for` loop. The `for` loop is the straight forward answer. I don't know what you mean by "python doesn't 'care' about mutability" because it certainly does.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in your question is very closed, here are two working versions.

#### Option 1 use enumerate

If you prefer to access `json` by `index`, `enumerate` is what you are looking for:

```
for i, x in enumerate(json):
    if x['id'] == 2:
        json[i]['name'] = 'something'

print(json) # what you want
```

#### Option 2 directly modify `x`

From your example, you actually don't need the index `i`.
You can directly modify `x` to achieve this.
The reason is that when iterating a list through `for x in`, `x` is a reference to the original item in the list, not a copy, so any modification to `x` will be reflected in the original list.

```
for x in json:
    if x['id'] == 2:
        x['name'] = 'something'

print(json) # what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python has `map` and friends, see
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html .

As others stated, it's more pythonic to just use for loops.
But if you want to use (and abuse) functional programming style, you can do it as:

```
any(map(lambda item: (item['id'] == 2) and item.update(name='something'), json))
```

The same with some comments:

```
any( # map will return an iterator, any is there to force the evaluation on each element
    map(
         lambda item:          # function to be applied
             (item['id'] == 2) # our condition
             and               # 'and' is lazy evaluated, if 'id' != 2
                               # we don't evaluate the following line
             item.update(      # update item with another dict
                 name = 'something' # use the fact that keyword arguments are given as a dict
             ), # the return value will always be false
                # forcing 'any' to look further
         json                  # the list we apply the map to
       )
   )
```

Comment: That seriously is snake abuse… ಠ_ಠ

Comment: what does it means? sounds funny haha.

Comment: @AndreThonas I added comments for you

Answer (score -1):

Python have all these functions like map, reduce, and filter.
Please refer https://www.learnpython.org/en/Map,_Filter,_Reduce

You also can use the list comprehension feature which is quite useful and handy.
Here I have written the list_comprehension for getting the list of specified condition which is id is 2 here.

```
output_list = [i.get("name") for i in json if i.get("id") == 2]
```

expected output

```
['b']
```